# Create a non-minimizable window which sticks to the desktop

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I have thought about creating a simple filesharing application. It should be easy-to-use and intuitive: Simply select a file from your filesystem and drag&drop it to e.g. the top right corner of your screen and the file(s) get distributed in the LAN.

The problem is that as soon as the user presses `Win + D` the designated drop-zone mimimizes or simply gets invisible. I've already tried a few solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794612/pin-wpf-window-on-the-desktop-in-windows-7) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350934/pin-to-desktop-in-win-7-xp-compatible) but none of them seems "right" for the purpose of my program. 
Probably some of you will know programs capable of acting in that way (I knew a program capable of that, but I cannot remember its name ...)

Everything apart from that is working, I have a normal UI supporting multiple file transmission at once and an integrated chat for sharing web-links.

Any ideas on how to add this quite pecular functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle the Minimize event and restore the window back.
Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938924/get-the-minimize-box-click-of-a-wpf-window) regarding the detection of window minimize event.